# bash: display only files that contain a date in their file name

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to figure out the best method to accomplishing this task, where I have a directory that has multiple files with varying file name formats, and I need to parse out those files that have a date in the file name (format of %F, or YYYY-MM-DD) from those that don't, then iterate through each of them using a mix of a for loop and a case loop to segregate between files that have a date in the file name and those that don't.  Pseudo code is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`ls`
for file in $files; do
  # Command to determine whether $file has a date string
  case (does variable have a date string?) in
    has)   # do something ;;
    hasnt) # do something else ;;
  esac
done
```

What is the best command to plug in for the comment, and then easiest way to execute such a case statement based off the command?

Comment: is for and case a requirement? why not use find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your original code, you can do

```
files=`ls`
for file in $files; do
  # Command to determine whether $file has a date string
  case ${file} in
    *2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]* )   
       # note that this date-only matching reg-exp is imperfect
       # it will match non-dates like 2011-19-39
       # but for cases where date is generated with date %F 
       # it will work OK
       : # do something 
    ;;
    * ) # do something else ;;
  esac
done
```

Or as @matchw recommends, you can use that pattern in a find

```
find . -type f -name '*2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3]-[0-9]*' -print0 \
  | xargs yourCommand
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: If you're going to use `find|xargs` like that, use the `-print0` option to `find` and the `-0` option to `xargs` so that you're armored against filenames with “unfriendly” characters (e.g., space) in.

Comment: The above whould match say 2011-19-39

Comment: Excellent, thank you for showing the example with the pseudo-code!

Comment: @George Kastrinis : Yes agreed. Thanks for documenting that limitation. I will add it as a comment.

Comment: @DonalFellows : thanks for that tip. Is print0 a GNU find specfic feature? I never saw it on solaris or aix. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Use grep with a regular expression

Something like

```
grep -E "20[0-9]{2}\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])"
```

eg.

```
echo "FOO_2011-05-12" | grep -E "20[0-9]{2}\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])"
```